# Filtering HTML user input for display

Tags: html, xss, filtering

I have a form where a user can enter text, which will later be displayed somewhere on the site. I want to allow so type of formatting, not just plain text. Am I right in thinking that if I filter out `<script>`, `<link>`, `<style>` and `<object>` tags I am safe from users changing the layout or injecting XSS and other horrors?

Comment: no you are not right... consider working with a white list instead of black list

Answer (score 0):

Just after sending the question, I relized that that obviously is not enough, since any tag can have an `onClick` attribute with JS code in it.
Oops.